# Extracting Text Using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract text from an older webpage, and having trouble. Inspecting the source of the webpage (http://www.presidency.ucsb.edu/ws/index.php?pid=119039), the text begins:

```
> </div></div><span class="displaytext"><b>PARTICIPANTS:</b><br>Former Secretary of State
> Hillary Clinton (D) and<br>Businessman Donald Trump
> (R)<p><b>MODERATOR:</b><br>Chris Wallace (Fox News)<p><b>WALLACE:</b>
> Good evening from the Thomas and Mack Center at the University of
> Nevada, Las Vegas. I'm Chris Wallace of Fox News, and I welcome you to
> the third and final of the 2016 presidential debates between Secretary
> of State Hillary Clinton and Donald J. Trump.<p>
```

I have tried extracting the text using:

```
link = "http://www.presidency.ucsb.edu/ws/index.php?pid=119039"
debate_response = requests.get(link)
debate_soup = BeautifulSoup(debate_response.content, 'html.parser')
debate_text = debate_soup.find_all('div',{'span class':"displaytext"})
print(debate_text)
```

but this just returns an empty list. Any idea how I can extract the text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to use [`lxml`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser) as the parser because I was getting a max recursion error using `html.parser`. The following will extract all text from the `<span>` tag's children into one string:

```
debate_soup = BeautifulSoup(debate_response.content, 'lxml')
debate_text = debate_soup.find('span', {'class': 'displaytext'}).get_text()
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you